# Why the selected row can not be deleted in table

Tags: jquery-easyui

In my project, I use easyui.

For convenience, I use edatagrid plugin.

I have defined table like this:

```
<div class="table" style="height:100%;width:100%;padding-bottom:50px">
  <table id="storInfoTB" idField="SNV" border=1px cellspacing=0 style="width:100%"  data-options=""></table>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#storInfoTB").edatagrid({  
  .......
  destroyUrl: "storInfo_destroy.php",
  .......
  columns:[[
      {field:"SNV",title:"id",width:40},
      {field:"CV",title:"note",width:50,editor:"text"}
       ]],
  toolbar: [{
        id: "delete",   
        text: "delete",
        iconCls: "icon-cut",
        handler: function(data){
          $("#storInfoTB").edatagrid("destroyRow");
        }           
      }],
   });
 });
```

The content of storInfo_destroy.php is:

```
$idNum=$_REQUEST['id'];
include("DB.php");

$sql="delete from  hpc_table  where id='$idNum';"; 
$selR=$conn->query($sql);

echo json_encode(array(
  'isError' => true, 
  'msg' => 'error message.'
)); 

// echo json_encode(array(
// 'success'=>true,
// ));
```

I have found that the selected data can be deleted in DB, but the selected row in table isn't deleted.

I have tested when destroyUrl is commentd, the seleted row can be deleted in table successfully, like this:

```
//destroyUrl: "storInfo_destroy.php"
```

But the selected data DB can not be deleted.

So who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

GOD!!, it should be return success

```
destroyUrl: null,   // return {success:true}
```

so, it is ok like:

```
$idNum=$_REQUEST['id'];
include("DB.php");

$sql="delete from  hpc_table  where id='$idNum';"; 
$selR=$conn->query($sql);

echo json_encode(array(
'success'=>true,
));
```